# trying to compare file with a dictionary python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

basically i'm trying to read the file below and comparing the fruit that the person wants with the fruit in the dictionary and if the stock is above 0 then print a message saying they have been given the fruit and if stock is 0 then a message saying not fruit was given etc.

the error im getting is: "IndexError: list index out of range" on the first line of my if statement

```
[
["James Bruce", "Bananas"],
["Katherine Newton", "Bananas"],
["Deborah Garcia", "Pears"],
["Marguerite Kozlowski", "Pineapples"],
["Kenneth Fitzgerald", "Pineapples"],
["Ronald Crawford", "Bananas"],
["Donald Haar", "Apples"],
["Al Whittenberg", "Bananas"],
["Max Bergevin", "Bananas"],
["Carlos Doby", "Pears"],
["Barry Hayes", "Pineapples"],
["Donald Haar", "Bananas"]
]
```

the dictionary: {"Apples": 14, "Bananas": 14, "Pineapples": 0, "Pears": 8}

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("C:\Users\dylan gornall\Desktop\Dylan's Uni Work\stock.json") as f:
a = f.read()
dic = literal_eval(a)
print(dic["Apples"])

s = open ("C:\Users\dylan gornall\Desktop\Dylan's Uni Work\queue.json", 'r')
for line in s:
parts = line.split(',')

if parts[1] == ("pears") + dic["Pears"] > 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif parts[1] == ("Apples") + dic["Apples"] > 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif parts[1] == ("Bananas") + dic["Bananas"] > 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif parts[1] == ("Pineapples") + dic["Pineapples"] > 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )
```

Comment: You've made a good start at posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow/help/mcve).  However, we don't have access to your C: drive.  You've given us the file contents, but why not just assign the variable in the MCVE?

Comment: Re: `if parts[1] == ("pears") + dic["Pears"] > 1 :` ... The parentheses are unnecessary and `+` should be `and`.  Also probably want `>= 1` and the correct case for `"Pears"`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your JSON input file is an open bracket.  When you `split()` it, you will get only one item in the list, but you're trying to access the second item.

Consider using the Python `json` module to input the JSON: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html .